Is my ad hoc opening particularly good or bad for White?
I've been playing chess for a little while now, but I haven't had a good, strong opening. I've flipped between one ad hoc opening and a variant of the French Defence (again, ad hoc), on and off, and have been considering learning the Sicilian Dragon (along with some other Sicilian Defence variants). However, the one I've used most commonly (1. b3 2. Bb2 3. e3/4 4. Ne2 5. O-O 6. g3/4 7. Bg2 8. d3 9. Nd2) is less than optimal even by my own review (the fianchettoed king is relatively weak, for one thing) and I've been wondering how it well it stands up to openings with actual, specific ideas behind them.

Please take time to visit the Help Center (https://chess.stackexchange.com/help) to find out what type of questions are welcome. Opinion based questions are not welcome and nor are multiple questions in one post.

How are you playing O-O before Bg2?

@DM I might've swapped 1. b3 2. Bb3 and 6.g3 and 7. Bg2 by accident.

@BrianTowers Sorry! I'll remember that from the future.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopotamus_Defence

You also want Bb2, not Bb3.

What black does matters, this opening may be great or really horrible depending on what black has been up to in the meantime.
